# How to Install and Configure SWAT In Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: samba

How to install SWAT (Samba Web Administration Tool) in 12.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a terminal write:

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbfs samba-doc swat xinetd
```

Enable service SWAT in **/etc/xinetd.conf** and restart with the new configuration by the following:

```
sudo update-inetd --enable 'swat'

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xinetd
```

Create new configuration file **/etc/xinetd.d/swat**:

```
sudo cat > /etc/xinetd.d/swat <<-EOF

service swat
{
port = 901
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/swat
log_on_failure += USERID
disable = no
}
EOF
```

Change the permissions **smb.conf** to group administrator **(adm)**.

use `chmod` and `chgrp` tools to change the file access permissions and group permissions respectively:

```
sudo chmod g+w /etc/samba/smb.conf

sudo chgrp adm /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Restart service **xinetd** with following command:

```
sudo service xinetd restart
```

open your web browser and access http://samba_server:[port]. **default port: 901**

If successful, you will be presented with a dialog box asking for username and password.

[image]

Use the username and a password from the admin group to log in, and you’ll have access to SWAT.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There an error ocuride in ubuntu 12.04, try http://joyit.ru/ubuntu/24-swat-samba-ubuntu-12-10.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.